# NHibernate base and derived class mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, class, mapping, radix

Situation:
I have a class **MyClass** and its "lightweight" version **MyClassLite**, so i have

```
public class MyClass : MyClassLite
```

I also use **hbm** file for mapping my classes (they are mapped to the same table).
The thing is that when i try to get a list of **MyClassLite** entities, i get not only **MyClassLite** entities, but a list of **MyClass** entities moreover. How can i rid of that?

Comment: Isn't this logical? MyClass is subclass of MyClassLite, so any MyClass instance is also instace of MyClassLite.

Change your inheritance hierarchy, if you want to get rid of them. E.g. introduce a base class and make both MyClass and MyClassLite subclasses of it.

Comment: It looks like it's logical, but I wonder if there any option, maybe in hbm file, to prevent from retrieving derived instances. There has to be something..

Comment: How are you querying this table for a list of MyClassLite?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is this ClassLite ?  Why does your Class inherit from ClassLite ?  Is there really an 'IS-A' relationship here ?

What is the reason of existence for ClassLite ? Is it a class which you use when, for instance, you have to display an overview of 'Class' instances ?
Then, if this is the case, you should have a look at DTO's or 'Views', Projections and the AliasToBeanEntityResultTransformer.

Answer (score 0):

If you configure eager loading for the list in the mapping or in the query, you will get the MyClass implementation.

In a criteria query:

```
Criteria.SetFetchmode("MyClassListProperty", Fetchmode.Eager)
```

in an hql query:

```
left join fetch MyClassListProperty
```

in the mapping file:

```
<set [...] lazy="false"> ...
```